# Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap doesn't load models

Tags: zend-framework, config, autoload, bootstrapping

I am using Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap, but framework can't load modeles.

**Index.php**

```
define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
define('APP_PATH', realpath( ROOT_PATH . '/application'));

set_include_path(realpath(ROOT_PATH . '/library') . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
$app = new Zend_Application('dev', APP_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
$app->bootstrap()->run();
```

**Application.ini**

```
bootstrap = APP_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

phpSettings.display_errors = on
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = on
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL|E_STRICT
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APP_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = on
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8"
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APP_PATH "/views/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "foo"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

**Bootstrap.php:**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
}
```

**Folder tree:**

```
Myproject->
/application
   /configs
   /controllers
   /models
      /Mytest.php
   /views
   Bootstrap.php
/public
   index.php
```

**Problem:**
I trying to create new Mytest() in controller, but i get "class not found in..."
When I add to bootstrap Zend_Loader::loadClass('Mytest', APP_PATH . '/models/') everything works.

**My questions** is, how to setup Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap via application.ini to autoload models folder ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model classes are by default named in ZF under 'Application' namespace.
So your class would be named as 'Application_Model_Mytest'

You can set the default namespace 'Application' by adding this to the application.ini

```
appnamespace = "Application"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But it is possible to have model classes named in old way?
I mean I don't want to use prefix **Application_Model_**.

Tryed to set (but prefix **Model_** is still needed):

    appnamespace = "Application"

I used old zend bootstrap before (inly included class Bootstrap {}) and there it was possible.

Comment: To autoload a class named `MyModel` that resides in the file `application/models/MyModel.php`, you could add the `application/models` folder to your `include_path` and set the standard autoloader as the fallback autoloader. But prefixing with at least some pseudo-namespacing - whether a full `Application_Model_` or even just `Model_` still strikes me as a good practice.